# Python setter to also return a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, setter, getter-setter

I was wondering if it would be possible to have a property setter to also return a value. The code below tries to explain superficially the problem.

Basically I need to set a property to an object, but before I need to check if it is unique. I was wondering if there is a way to the return the unique name to the user directly, without needing to query the object for its new name afterwards.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,ID):
        self._ID = ID
    @property
    def Name(self):
        return DBGetName(self._ID)

    @Name.setter
    def Name(self, value):
        UniqueName = DBGetUniqueName(self._ID,value)
        return DBSetName(UniqueName)

Myinstance = MyClass(SomeNumber)
#What I do now
Myinstance.Name = "NewName"
Uniquename = Myinstance.Name

#What I was wondering if possible. Line below is syntactically invalid, but shows the idea.
Name = (Myinstance.Name = "NewName")
```

Edit:
It is a pseudo code and I forgot to actually pass the value to the inner function. My bad.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this. It looks like the setter completely ignores the value you pass it. A setter that took `MyInstance.Name = "NewName"` and set the name to `"NewName-071839"` I'd understand, but this would throw me (even in JavaScript or C# or another language that allows it).

Comment: Well, it's syntactically valid to do `Name = Myinstance.Name = "NewName"`, but the return value of the setter will be ignored, and it'll just set `Name` to `"NewName"`.

Comment: @Aya: Good point. Without the parentheses, this would be a chained assignment statement, which means "assign this value to all of the chained-together names". In very simple cases, that does the same thing as C/JS/etc. "assign this value to the last name, then assign the result of that assignment to the one before it, …", but in this case it doesn't help.

Comment: @abarnert Sure. Though, if you've come from a C++ background, and you've used `operator=` you might have expectations of being able to do something similar in Python. TBH, I'm glad you can't use an assignment as an expression in Python - I still mistype `if foo == 1` as `if foo = 1` on occasion, particularly when I'm switching between Python and SQL coding, and it's nice that Python spots that particular bug for me, because it's easily missed.

Comment: @Aya: Another good point. Chained assignment is superficially similar to C++ in _two_ potentially-novice-confusing ways, instead of just the one way that C and JS have… Anyway, I'm also glad that Python doesn't allow assignment expressions, but it's more about being part of a whole set of features that make almost all Python code structured in a much more readable way than almost any JS or C++ code.

Comment: @abarnert Agreed. As a novice programmer, it's easy to shoot yourself in the foot with any language, but, IMO, where Python gives you a single chambered round, C gives you a full clip, and C++ gives you infinite ammo. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A setter certainly *can* return a value.

But it isn't very useful to do so, because setters are generally used in assignment statements—as in your example.

The problem is that in Python, assignment is not an expression, it's a statement. It doesn't have a value that you can use, and you can't embed it in another statement. So, there is no way to write the line you want to write.

You can instead call the setter explicitly… but in that case, it's a lot clearer to just write it as a regular method instead of a property setter.

---

And in your case, I think a regular method is exactly what you want. You're completely ignoring the value passed to the setter. That's going to confuse readers of your code (including you in 6 months). It's not really a setter at all, it's a function that creates a unique name. So, why not call it that?

```
def CreateUniqueName(self):
    UniqueName = DBGetUniqueName(self._ID)
    return DBSetName(UniqueName)
```

(It's worth noting that `DBSetName` returning its argument is itself not very Pythonic…)

---

If you're wondering *why* Python works this way, see [Why can't I use an assignment in an expression?](http://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression) from the official FAQ.

More generally, the expression-statement distinction, together with associated features like mutating methods (e.g., `list.sort`) returning `None` instead of `self`, leads to a simpler, more regular language. Of course there's a cost, in that it leads to a much less fluent language. There's an obvious tradeoff, and Python is about as far to the extreme as you can get. (Compare to JavaScript, which is about as far to the *opposite* extreme as you can get.) But most people who love Python think it made the right tradeoff.

Comment: Yeah that's the conclusion I came to. I also agree that it makes it difficult to read the code, but I got curious if it was possible.

Comment: This answer is no longer current as of Python3.8, which supports the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression) to use an assignment in an expression.

Comment: The walrus operator does not support attributes, including properties.

Comment: See solution below.

Comment: The solutions below does not apply to the question's problem. But the walrus operator is in deed helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I started with a similar question, but I only needed to get 'generic' information from a setter in order to automate GUI creation; The GUI code looks through a list of attributes, finds those that have setters and then creates input fields. However some inputs are strings, others floats etc. and the GUI code generates appropriate input fields. I know this is a kludge, but I put that information in the docstring for the getter.

I realise this is not an answer to your question but might help someone looking like I was!

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = None
        return
    @property
    def name(self):
        """Doggos are the best!"""
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, n):
        self._name = n
        return
def main():
    terrier = Dog()
    terrier.name = "Rover"
    print("Dog's name is ", terrier.name)
    print(type(terrier).name.__doc__)
    # also works with...
    print(getattr(type(terrier), 'name').__doc__)
    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python3.8 or greater:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,ID):
        self._ID = ID
    @property
    def Name(self):
        return DBGetName(self._ID)

    @Name.setter
    def Name(self, value):
        UniqueName = DBGetUniqueName(self._ID,value)
        return DBSetName(UniqueName)

Myinstance = MyClass(SomeNumber)

Myinstance.Name = (Uniquename := Myinstance.Name) # Python >= 3.8
```

Comment: Does not work if assignment expressions with attribute. For instance: `Uniquename = (Myinstance.Name := 'someName')` (leads to SyntaxError)

Comment: True. Assignment expressions with attributes are not supported per [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)